# Raspberry PI 3, SerialPort and strange response

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bit-manipulation, pyserial

I'm trying to control my old [Samsung DLP SP-A600B](http://www.samsung.com/fr/support/model/SPA600BX/EN) with the Serial Port (jack). To do so, I have resused my Raspberry Pi 3, and I have plugged a USB to Jack cable (UART) that I found on the net.

I made a small Python file but I don't understand the output I'm receiving. Here's my code:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ON = b"\x08,\x22,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\xD6"
# other hard-coded commands

ser.write(ON)
time.sleep(1)
out = ser.read(3)

# 0x03 0x0C 0x7F doesn't match the spec!

print out
ser.close()
```

According [to the manual](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_FR&CttFileID=2409473&CDCttType=UM&ModelType=N&ModelName=SP-A600&VPath=UM/200908/20090826081717796/BP59-00137A-02Eng.pdf):

> ### 5-2 RS-232C Command Table
>
> ### Communication Format (Complies with the RS232C Standard)
>
> - Baud rate : 9,600 bps
> - parity : None
> - Data bits : 8, stop bit : 1
> - Flow Control : None
>
> ### Serial Communication Protocol
>
> 1. Command Packet Structure [7bytes]
>
>    - A command packet consists of 7 bytes in total.
>    - The two bytes 0x08 and 0x22 signify that the packet is for serial communication.
>    - The following 4 bytes represent a pre-defined command that can be defined by the user.
>    - The last byte is the checksum which checks the validity of the current packet.
>    - Header [2 Byte]: Pre-defined values fixed to 0x08 and 0x22.
>    - Cmd1 [1 Byte]: The first value of the code defined in the command list (Hexadecimal)
>    - Cmd2 [1 Byte]: The second value of the code defined in the command list (Hexadecimal)
>    - Cmd3 [1 Byte]: The third value of the code defined in the command list (Hexadecimal)
>    - Value [1 Byte]: Input parameter for the command (Default: 0) (Hexadecimal)
>    - CS [1 Byte]: Checksum (the 2’s complement of the sum of all the values except for the CS value.)
> 2. Response Packet Structure [3 Bytes]
>
>    1. Success
>
>    0x03 0x0C 0xF1
>
>    2. Fail
>
>    0x03 0x0C 0xFF

I used this [website](http://www.planetimming.com/checksum8.html) to calculate the 2’s complement (I'm more NodeJS / Android guy) for the 7th byte (D6). Unfortunately, I only receive

```
0x03 0x0C 0x7F
```

for this command. If I try to set strange values like serial.PARITY_ODD or serial.EIGHTBITS I receive the fail packet

```
0x03 0x0C 0xFF
```

And I did not succeed to receive one success packet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are getting `0x7f` as your last byte because you have set `serial.SEVENBITS` and that is the 7-bit representation of `0xff`. I think you need to set `serial.EIGHTBITS`

Comment: You're right: `0xFF` is `11111111` and `0x7F` is `01111111`. So in the end, I just receive Fail Packets :(

Comment: Maybe it's the cable, I bought a "TipRX RingTX SlvGND" cable and I had another choice "TipTX RingRX SlvGND", I don't know how I can be sure...

Comment: I don't speak Python, but I wonder about the commas in your string. Can you try `ON = b"\x08\x22\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD6"` and EIGHTBIT.

Comment: Yes it's working! Perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we eventually worked out in the comments, the problem is that there are superfluous commas in the command string and the data need to be 8-bit.

So, in concrete terms, use:

```
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
...
...
ON = b"\x08\x22\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD6"
```